# How to load FLV in AviSynth?

Tags: flv, avisynth, ffdshow

How do i load an FLV in AviSynth. The standard:

```
DirectShowSource("2011 Visa Championships.flv")
```

fails with:

> Video returned: "DirectShowSource: couldn't open file 2011 Visa Championships.flv:
>   Cannot play back the file. The format is not supported."
>
> Audio returned: "DirectShowSource: couldn't open file 2011 Visa Championships.flv:
>   Cannot play back the file. The format is not supported."

i have `ffdshow` installed; but i wouldn't know how to convince AviSynth to use it - if i even can.

---

With no FLVSplitter registered:

- Cannot play back the file. The format is not supported.

With Gabest `FLVSplitter.ax` v1.0.0.1 (3/20/2006, md5:`BDF94AC91ECA14B6AA3364C45740A09E`):

- Pins cannot connect due to not supporting the same transport.

With Gabest `FLVSplitter.ax` v1.0.0.1 Unicode (3/20/2006, md5:`6FC6C7EDC3A090A6066E3E790727ABA8`):

- Pins cannot connect due to not supporting the same transport.

With Gabest `FLVSplitter.ax` v1.0.0.5 (11/15/2008, md5:`37AD5345CB08C167821F2CAACA08AA26`):

- No error, but playback never starts

With Gabest `FLVSplitter.ax` v1.0.0.5 (4/28/2009, md5:`C82070D55D0B25E87185C874518D71DB`):

- No error, but playback never starts

With Media Player Classic playing the file directly using its own internal FLV Splitter:

- Plays fine

How do i load an FLV in AviSynth?

---

When loaded with GSpot, the **MS A/V** render is able to build a filter graph; and play the video.

Loading the `.avs` file in **Windows Media Player** (or Media Player Classic) gives no playback.

---

### MediaInfo

```
General
Count                            : 279
Count of stream of this kind     : 1
Kind of stream                   : General
Kind of stream                   : General
Stream identifier                : 0
Inform                           : Flash Video: 78.2 MiB, 15mn 0s
Count of video streams           : 1
Count of audio streams           : 1
Video_Format_List                : AVC
Video_Format_WithHint_List       : AVC
Codecs Video                     : AVC
Audio_Format_List                : AAC
Audio_Format_WithHint_List       : AAC
Audio codecs                     : AAC LC
Complete name                    : C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\videocacheview\2011 Visa Championships.flv
Folder name                      : C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\videocacheview
File name                        : 2011 Visa Championships
File extension                   : flv
Format                           : Flash Video
Format                           : Flash Video
Format/Url                       : http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer
Format/Extensions usually used   : flv
Commercial name                  : Flash Video
Internet media type              : application/x-shockwave-flash
Codec                            : Flash Video
Codec                            : Flash Video
Codec/Url                        : http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer
Codec/Extensions usually used    : flv
File size                        : 82000490
File size                        : 78.2 MiB
File size                        : 78 MiB
File size                        : 78 MiB
File size                        : 78.2 MiB
File size                        : 78.20 MiB
Duration                         : 900668
Duration                         : 15mn 0s
Duration                         : 15mn 0s 668ms
Duration                         : 15mn 0s
Duration                         : 00:15:00.668
Overall bit rate                 : 728348
Overall bit rate                 : 728 Kbps
Stream size                      : 985234
Stream size                      : 962 KiB (1%)
Stream size                      : 962 KiB
Stream size                      : 962 KiB
Stream size                      : 962 KiB
Stream size                      : 962.1 KiB
Stream size                      : 962 KiB (1%)
Proportion of this stream        : 0.01201
File creation date               : UTC 2011-08-24 23:42:44.580
File creation date (local)       : 2011-08-24 19:42:44.580
File last modification date      : UTC 2011-08-24 23:42:44.753
File last modification date (loc : 2011-08-24 19:42:44.753
httphostheader                   : v20.lscache6.c.youtube.com

Video
Count                            : 201
Count of stream of this kind     : 1
Kind of stream                   : Video
Kind of stream                   : Video
Stream identifier                : 0
Inform                           : 591 Kbps, 640*480 (4:3), at 30.000 fps, AVC (Main@L3.0) (CABAC / 3 Ref Frames)
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                       : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Commercial name                  : AVC
Format profile                   : Main@L3.0
Format settings                  : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames        : 3
Format settings, ReFrames        : 3 frames
Format settings, GOP             : M=1, N=30
Internet media type              : video/H264
Codec ID                         : 7
Codec                            : AVC
Codec                            : AVC
Codec/Family                     : AVC
Codec/Info                       : Advanced Video Codec
Codec/Url                        : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Codec profile                    : Main@L3.0
Codec settings                   : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Codec settings, CABAC            : Yes
Codec_Settings_RefFrames         : 3
Duration                         : 900701
Duration                         : 15mn 0s
Duration                         : 15mn 0s 701ms
Duration                         : 15mn 0s
Duration                         : 00:15:00.701
Bit rate                         : 590906
Bit rate                         : 591 Kbps
Width                            : 640
Width                            : 640 pixels
Height                           : 480
Height                           : 480 pixels
Pixel aspect ratio               : 1.000
Display aspect ratio             : 1.333
Display aspect ratio             : 4:3
Frame rate mode                  : CFR
Frame rate mode                  : Constant
FrameRate_Mode_Original          : VFR
Frame rate                       : 30.000
Frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Frame count                      : 27021
Resolution                       : 8
Resolution                       : 8 bits
Colorimetry                      : 4:2:0
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Scan type                        : Progressive
Interlacement                    : PPF
Interlacement                    : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.064
Delay                            : 0
Delay                            : 00:00:00.000
Delay, origin                    : Container
Delay, origin                    : Container
Stream size                      : 66528703
Stream size                      : 63.4 MiB (81%)
Stream size                      : 63 MiB
Stream size                      : 63 MiB
Stream size                      : 63.4 MiB
Stream size                      : 63.45 MiB
Stream size                      : 63.4 MiB (81%)
Proportion of this stream        : 0.81132

Audio
Count                            : 169
Count of stream of this kind     : 1
Kind of stream                   : Audio
Kind of stream                   : Audio
Stream identifier                : 0
Inform                           : 129 Kbps, 44.1 KHz, 2 channels, AAC (LC)
Format                           : AAC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec
Commercial name                  : AAC
Format profile                   : LC
Codec ID                         : 10
Codec                            : AAC LC
Codec                            : AAC LC
Codec/Family                     : AAC
Duration                         : 900632
Duration                         : 15mn 0s
Duration                         : 15mn 0s 632ms
Duration                         : 15mn 0s
Duration                         : 00:15:00.632
Bit rate                         : 128679
Bit rate                         : 129 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 2
Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
Channel positions                : Front: L R
Channel positions                : 2/0/0
Sampling rate                    : 44100
Sampling rate                    : 44.1 KHz
Samples count                    : 39717871
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Delay                            : 0
Delay                            : 00:00:00.000
Delay, origin                    : Container
Delay, origin                    : Container
Delay relative to video          : 0
Video0 delay                     : 0
Stream size                      : 14486553
Stream size                      : 13.8 MiB (18%)
Stream size                      : 14 MiB
Stream size                      : 14 MiB
Stream size                      : 13.8 MiB
Stream size                      : 13.82 MiB
Stream size                      : 13.8 MiB (18%)
Proportion of this stream        : 0.17666
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the *Video decoder configuration* shortcut:

> Start -> **Video decoder configuration**

to set the decoder for **FLV1** and **VP6F** to *libavcodec* in the Codecs section:

[image]

If that does not work, install the [Gabest FLVSplitter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/files/FLV%20Splitter/).

Also, try using the [`FFmpegSource`](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/FFmpegSource)`()` plugin for AVISynth instead of `DirectShowSource ()`.

Perhaps there is something unusual about the video file itself. Check it with [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to see if you have the required codecs installed. Also run it through [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) for more detailed information about the video.

Comment: It already is configured to use *libvacodec*.

Comment: In this case i am trying to use `SegmentedDirectShowSource`, to merge 7 parts (e.g. `SegmentedDirectShowSource("2011 Visa Championships.flv")`), which in turn uses `DirectShowSource` on all the videos.

Comment: Did you try the FLVSplitter? Also, do all of the source videos have the same formate (eg dimensions, frame-rate, etc.)?

Comment: i tried registering an FLV splitter `flvsplitter.ax` that was dated 2009 (as opposed to Gabest which is 2006). AviSynth then didn't give an error, but started playing any video (even after 10 minutes; it just sat there at a black player screen). Tonight i'll try unregistering the `flvsplitter.ax` and register Gabest's `flvsplitter.ax`.

Comment: What program are you using? I just created an AVS file with the line you had (and changing the file-name), and was able to play it in MPC (and got a prompt asking me for permission to use ffdshow), and I was able to open it in VirtualDub.